# Script is not calling on Homepage Banner slider

Tags: magento2.2.6, banner-slider

https://www.depoto.com/ is my website.

I have used the weltpixel banner slider extension.
When i refresh the website, The banner slider is not working properly.

[image]

Comment: have you deleted the question that you have asked previously?

Comment: I think it is working now

Comment: Is it working now with my given answer?

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI, Thanks for the answer. Actually its not worked. then i chose another plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a class issue while loading the content it is not appending this class -> `owl-carousel` some times.

What you can do to resolve this issue is just simply put a script on the home page & add the class there with your own script like this

```
<script>
    require(['jquery'], function($){
       $('.owl-carousel-custom-1.owl-theme.owl-loaded.owl-drag').addClass('owl-carousel');
    });
</script>
```

There must be some other solution also but it is the short hack that you can do for resolving this issue now

> **Note:** You can simply put the if condition to the script for checking that if
>   class is already there or not to overcome the double assignment of the
>   same class.

Thank You!

Comment: i have added at homepage. But still the problem is apearing . Please check once

Comment: as I can see into your site in console you are getting one error that is jQuery is not defined so please call that script with the require js content that is the dependency on the jquery see my updated answer!

Comment: still i am having the same problem. I have added your updated one in my homepage

Comment: I think that is your browser cache issue please try with some other browser or after removing the browser cache or in a incognito mode, flush the magento cache & also please remove that old code with `jQuery` as because that I am still can see into the console it is giving error there